# Clustered Indexes physical storage

Tags: sql

Can a Clustered index store the actual physical data in the order of the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most SQL database implementations structure a database table without indices in the form of a heap — an unordered collection of related pages, each containing some number of rows.

Non-clustered indices are B-trees, the leaf nodes of which contain pointers to the data pages containing that key value. Getting a non-key value via a non-clustered index requires an additional lookup to retrieve the data page in question.

Clustered indices, like non-clustered indices, are B-trees, with one important difference: the heap goes away. The leaf nodes of the clustered index **are** the data pages for the table: thus giving physical order to the table. The rows on each page, likewise are maintained in key order. Getting a non-key value via a clustered index doesn't require the overhead of of the additional lookup required to get the data page in question.

Answer (score 2):

That's what they do.

A clustered index is all the data in the table, stored in the physical order of the clustering key and with a supporting b-tree structure for quick navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Extending other answers...

- the data is in order of index key. Non-key columns have no order
- the order is logical: insert a new row in the middle and you may get a page split and some pointers
- physical order will exist after create or rebuild (subject to partitioning etc)
- the output order will **only** be guaranteed by ORDER BY

Answer (score 0):

A clustered index ***is*** an exact copy of the table, sorted by the field(s) of the index.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933131%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

> A clustered index determines the
>   physical order of data in a table. A
>   clustered index is analogous to a
>   telephone directory, which arranges
>   data by last name. Because the
>   clustered index dictates the physical
>   storage order of the data in the
>   table, a table can contain only one
>   clustered index. However, the index
>   can comprise multiple columns (a
>   composite index), like the way a
>   telephone directory is organized by
>   last name and first name.

So yes, a key point of a Clustered Index **is** to store the physical data in the order of the index.